# How to simulate exact browser request using PHP script?

Tags: php

I am trying to access a webpage using PHP file_get_contents(), but the server returns forbidden error. While if I visit the same page in a browser it works correctly. I tried to provide the headers but it does not seam to be working at all. Searched for two days what I got was some 11 year old topics which too were not working. What I Have done so far is:

```
<?php
$link = 'https://www.jk.gov.in/jkeservices/home';

$options = array(
'http' => array(
    'header'  => 'Host: www.jk.gov.in',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
    'DNT: 1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ur-PK;q=0.8,ur;q=0.7,da;q=0.6',
    'Cookie: JSESSIONID=A8CF3879FB9BCC7EC6DD314F4A4C57DF',
    'method'  => 'GET',
)
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = get_headers($link, 0, $context);
//$result = file_get_contents($link, false, $context);

var_dump($result);
//echo $result;
```

**The result I got from these two requests is same forbidden error.**

```
array(8) { [0]=> string(22) "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden" [1]=> string(35) "Date: Thu, 19 Nov 2020 02:43:40 GMT" [2]=> string(14) "Server: Apache" [3]=> string(51) "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN, SAMEORIGIN, SAMEORIGIN" [4]=> string(62) "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains" [5]=> string(19) "Content-Length: 225" [6]=> string(17) "Connection: close" [7]=> string(43) "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" }
```

**and for the other one that is comment :**

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.jk.gov.in/jkeservices/home): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in C:\xampp\htdocs\badtools\index.php on line 29
bool(false)
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated..

Comment: All the `header` values should be in an array.

Comment: I tried adding them in an array but the result is the same..

Comment: Try using `curl` instead of `file_get_content()`. It works with CLI curl without using any options.

Comment: Not working, it say moved (error 302) and permanently moved (error 301) by requesting without https and with https before url respectively.

Comment: @Barmar oddly true, works with [curl](https://www.tehplayground.com/smhL71RM6tBOZ2XK)

Comment: Use `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to follow redirects

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [postman](https://www.postman.com/). It will automatically create the php code from your request.

Step 1:
copy request as cUrl(cmd) using your browser (I use Chrome)

Step 2:
Click import on postman. Select raw text. paste copied request. imort it.

Step 3:
Select "code"

Step 4:
Select your preferred language.

[image]

It will generate your code automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need `curl` for this. The simplest way is that you will get the entire header from the browser when you successfully access the website. Then use a tool like `postman` and paste the header and test it. Eliminate unnecessary headers. finally attach it to the `curl`.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP functions that utilize [HTTP context](//php.net/context.http) options, you have to be
careful of this:

> `protocol_version` float
>
> HTTP protocol version.
>
> Defaults to `1.0`.

This particular server requires at least HTTP 1.1. Notice the same thing happens if you try to use HTTP 1.0 with normal old cURL:

```
PS C:\> curl.exe -0 -I www.jk.gov.in/jkeservices/home
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

To fix, do something like this:

```
<?php
$url_s = 'http://www.jk.gov.in/jkeservices/home';
$r = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($r, 'http', 'protocol_version', 1.1);
$a = get_headers($url_s, 0, $r);
print_r($a);
```

Edit: this [has been fixed](//github.com/php/php-src/commit/f9f769d4). So if you have PHP 8.0.0rc1 (Sep 2020) or higher
then you are good.